# Feature selection & significant features in kNN

Tags: machine-learning, salesforce, random-forest, knn

I am developing a recommendation engine with the help of kNN. Data, though, is sparse, have around 1500 samples and around 200 features. I have an ordinal target having values 1 or 0.

What would be the techniques to do feature selection for it? I am assuming that if i choose Random forest for feature selection then the selected features may be different that what kNN assume important features are.

Also, is there any restriction on the number of features containing i have so less number of samples?

Comment: Depending on how sparse the data, principal components might be appropriate.  If the data is very sparse, then association rules might be appropriate.

Comment: how to judge the sparseness of data? is there any matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Features selection techniques want either to exclude irrelevant features, or/and to exclude redundant ones. One proven technique is to use [Supervized discretization based on entropy](http://Recursive%20Minimal%20Entropy%20Partitioning%20algorithm%20proposed%20by%20Fayyad%20&%20Irani) (some more generic explanation can be found [here](http://kevinmeurer.com/a-simple-guide-to-entropy-based-discretization/)) to meaningfully reduce the size of your data, and then use Info Gain to get top k most correlated features with the target variable. There are at least 5 various methods that you can try, it also depends on the ml library/framework that you are using to implement your app.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with Relief algorithm, since its core part is the nearest neighbour search.